# stopService and stop get message

Tags: java, android, android-service

I Want to stop my service and stop get data to ma handler which I have in activity. And service I connect to USB and get data from this port.

**I try did this:**

```
usbService.stopSelf();
Intent intent = new Intent(MainMenu.this, UsbService.class);
usbService.stopService(intent);
```

but all the time I have a data from service.

**I start my service just like this:**

```
private void startService(Class<?> service, ServiceConnection serviceConnection, Bundle extras) {
if (!UsbService.SERVICE_CONNECTED) {
Intent startService = new Intent(this, service);
if (extras != null && !extras.isEmpty()) {
Set<String> keys = extras.keySet();
for (String key : keys) {
String extra = extras.getString(key);
startService.putExtra(key, extra);
}
}
startService(startService);
}
Intent bindingIntent = new Intent(this, service);
bindService(bindingIntent, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to unbind your service first, by calling unBindService. 
As you can see in the [Service documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services):

> Note that if a stopped service still has ServiceConnection objects
>   bound to it with the BIND_AUTO_CREATE set, it will not be destroyed
>   until all of these bindings are removed. See the Service documentation
>   for more details on a service's lifecycle.

you need to unbind all objects bound to the service before stopping it in order to destroy the service.

EDIT: Answer to your question. Add a boolean variable mBound. Override these methods.

```
public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
  mBound = true;
}
public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
  mBound = false;
}
```

In your activity's onStop method, add this:

```
@Override
public void onStop()
{
  super.onStop();

  if (mBound) {
    try {
      unbindService(mConnection);
    } catch (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException e)
    {
      //handle exception here
    }
  }
  mBound = false;
}
```

Comment: So what I to do ?Because I do not know